# Advice with Tab Bar and Nav Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'd just like to clear something up..

I have an app where the Main Window UI has a Tab bar with 3 tabs (opt1, opt2, op3). Each opt has its own xib file where i've drawn their own interfaces.

In my app delegate class I have included a UITabBar *rootController, and hooked this up to my tab bar in my Main Window xib file.

Now.. In the Tab bar, I have dragged in 3 navigation controllers (1 for each opt) and inside each one I have a 1) tab bar icon, 2) navigation bar and 3) view controller.

Back in my app delegate.h class I have included code for UINavigationController *nav1, nav2, nav3..and hooked these up accordingly in IB in MainWindow.xib (TabBar->navController1, navController2, navController3).

Is this the right way to do it? Also how can I make use of these nab bars in my opt1, opt2, opt3 class files?

here is my code:
app delegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LoginViewController;

@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController1, *navigationController2,     *navigationController3;
IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController1, *navigationController2, *navigationController3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;

@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
[window addSubview:[rootController view]]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
[self.rootController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];

}
```

Then in my LoginController.m class , when the user enters correct credentials I call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In my MainWindow.xib, I hook up my rootController to a TabBarController. In the TabBarController I have put 3 NavigationControllers inside it and linked them to 3 tabOption classes which each have their own .xib view.

The tab bar switches between the 3 option views nicely. However in 1 .xib view I have a button to open a new .xib. So in my tabOption1 class I have the following:

```
-(IBAction)openBook:(id)sender{

UIViewController *nextVC = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
}
```

However this does not open up my PageView.xib... I have connected it to my PageViewController class and everything too..and the button works because I've tested it with a UIDialog

Comment: Not really sure what your issue is here? Is something NOT working in your app. What you've described seems to be a good way of doing what you need. If you need any more help if you start XCode and choose a new Tab Bar Controller project then it will give you sample layouts and all sorts which will help you.

Comment: i just wanted some reassurance. It works...but say for example I create a button in my opt1 UI, and this button links to a new view. How do i access the navcontroller (which is declared in my app delegate) in my opt1 class and tell it to navigate to this other new view? I just don't get how I work with those navControllers in the opt1, opt2, opt3 classes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Apple Programming Guides? They might give you a better understanding of how everything ties together - you could start here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1

In answer to your question, that looks like an OK way of setting up. I really would recommend reading up a bit though :)

Comment: thanks for the link. i'll read through this now and see if i pick up anything new :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, that looks like a reasonable way to do what you're trying to achieve. If it works, then it works.

In response to your other issue then you can get the navigation controller object by doing this: `self.navigationController`

So you can "go to" a new view controller like this:

```
// make the view controller
UIViewController *nextVC = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustomViewController" bundle:nil];

// push it onto the navigation stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
```

To add this to the `click` event on a button you need to create the button in interface builder and create an `IBAction` in your code. The `IBAction` might look like this:

```
- (IBAction)pushNextViewController:(id)sender {
  UIViewController *nextVC = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustomViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
}
```

Then you need to link to it from interface builder. I'm not sure how to do this, I generally don't use interface builder, and certainly haven't used it since about XCode 3.

To do it programatically you can use this method:

```
[MyButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(pushNextViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // always use touch up inside
```

Keywords to look up to help you find tutorials and stuff on the internet: ibaction uinavigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:animated: popviewcontrolleranimated:

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive explanation. I understand you access the nav controller by using self.navigationController but if I have 3 nab controllers in my MainWindow.xib (1 nab controller for each tab bar view) then how does it know which nab bar it is accessing? Also for some reason I cannot switch views using the code that create a UIViewController instance..The button is linked because I've tested it with a UIDialog message..

Comment: I've forgotten my pointers, I will edit the question, this is possibly the issue. When you're in a view controller (e.g. in the `viewDidLoad` method) then `self.navigationController` will only access the navigation controller which the view is attached to, if you understand.

Comment: if you mean this pointer (UIViewController *nextVC ) then i already had tried that to get it to compile..so i'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: none.  This code works fine in my appDelegate to load a login view as a modalViewController..once logged in i dismiss that and i'm presented with my MainWindow.xib which has a tab bar with 3 view options to switch between. On one of the views I have a button to open this new view (using the code above) but it's not working..hmm

Comment: strange - can you post your code in the question please and then comment here again when you've done it (so I get a notification that you've posted your code)

Comment: ok uploaded. hope it's enough for you to understand. let me know if you need more

Comment: hmm, its not quite enough. How would you feel about sending me the code base? I can't understand why it wouldn't work. If you want me to have a look at the code send me a ZIP of the xcode project folder to `tclayson at gmail dot com` and I will have a look for you.